# Proving number of roots of a function using Rolle's theorem

Tags: calculus

I am given a function $f(x) = x^3 + 3x - 1$, and I am asked to prove that $f(x)$ has exactly one real root using the Intermediate Value Theorem and Rolle's theorem. So far, I managed to prove the existence of at least one real root using IVT.

Note that $f(x)$ is continuous and differentiable for all $x \in \Bbb R$. By inspection, since $f(-1) = -5$ and $f(1) = 3$, by the IVT, there exists a $c \in [-1, 1] $ such that $f(c) = 0$. Therefore, $f(x)$ must have at least one root. I am not sure if this is the best way to prove that it has at least one root - if there is a better way, please let me know. I don't know how I can use Rolle's theorem to prove that there is only one root. I had an idea of integrating the polynomial and then proving that it has just one maximum using Rolle's theorem but that did not work out so well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Between any two distinct real roots, there is, by Rolle's Theorem, a root of the derivative. But the derivative has no roots.

There is a perhaps somewhat better way to use IVT to show the *existence* of a root. Don't bother to find *explicit* $a$ and $b$ such that our function is negative at $a$ and positive at $b$. It is obvious that when $x$ is large enough negative, our function is negative, and that when $x$ is large enough positive, our function is positive. Thus *any* cubic has a real root. By the same argument, any polynomial of *odd* degree has a real root.

Comment: Ah, perfect - this is just what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

IVT shows the existence of the root and you can use the first derivative to see your function is increasing, which means it is the unique point which makes $f(x)$ zero.

Answer (score -1):

Rolle's Theorem always fails because there are no roots. Therefore, the maximum number of roots must be less than 2, making the maximum number of roots possible 1.